# add/remove classed in javascript

Tags: javascript

The following code will add class 'success' to the div but I want it to automatically remove 'success' after 2 seconds. Please help me

```js
document.onclick = function(event) {
   var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
   target.classList.add("success");
};
```

Comment: you can use setTimeout. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setTimeout, example with your code:

```js
document.onclick = function(event) {
   var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
   target.classList.add("success");
   setTimeout(() => {
    target.classList.remove("success");
   }, 2000);
};
```